# Is there a word for the final stone of a foundation?

Tags: single-word-requests

Is there a word for the final stone of a foundation? Analogous to the word "cornerstone"?

Comment: What about keystone?

Comment: I'm not sure builders would generally agree there's even such a *thing* as "the final stone of a foundation". In many constructions, the *first* one is easily identifiable (and is often referred to as just ***the*** foundation stone). The last structurally significant element is often called the ***capstone*** (here are 1000 written instances of ["foundation to capstone"](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22foundation+to+capstone%22&btnG=Search+Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1)). But OP's request is for something that doesn't really have a real-world referent in any significant sense.

Answer (score 4):

the [cornerstone](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/cornerstone?s=t) is technically a stone uniting any two masonry walls at an intersection, therefore all corners have cornerstones.

For use #2: "a stone representing the nominal starting place in the construction of a monumental building, usually carved with the date and laid with appropriate ceremonies." I would think the *last foundation stone* is your partner word(s).

I have searched for architectural references, but found only cornerstone and foundation stone(s). Apparently the last stone in a foundation does not deserve it's own appellation.

The opposite of foundation stone (which is originally what I thought you were asking) is the [*capstone*](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/capstone): The top stone of a structure or wall. The crowning achievement or final stroke; the culmination or acme.

From Wikipedia: [Coping](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coping_%28architecture%29) (from cope, Latin capa), consists of the capping or covering of a wall.

I believe in BrE, it is cope stone.

Answer (score 0):

Copestone, I think, is one choice.

Comment: A copestone is a capstone, which is mentioned in the other answer by @Susan as meaning the opposite of this concept.